# How to send a list from controller to jsp as a jquery ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

The $.post int the jsp is as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#searchtext").keyup(function(){
            $.post("search",
                    {
                      parameter:$("#searchtext").val()
                    },
                    function(response){
                       document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML=response;

                    });
      });
    });
```

The controller is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping("/search")
    public @ResponseBody ModelAndView searchByUser(@RequestParam(value="parameter" , required=false) String bookAttributesLike){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/homepage");
        if(bookAttributesLike == null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            try {
                    searchResults = bookManagerService.getBookList(bookAttributesLike);
                    modelAndView.addObject("message",searchResults);
            } catch (NoResultFoundException e) {
                modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/homepage");
                logger.info("No Book Found");
            }
            catch (ServiceException e) {
                modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/error");
                logger.error("Problem in fetching records");
            }
        }
        return modelAndView;
}
}
```

Now I am getting the list when I enter a word but the page gets refreshed and the first letter is gone. So what can be done to fetch the list and get the contents in the text box as well?

Answer (score 0):

Put the result in a div rather than rewriting the whole page.

Change:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML=response;
```

To something like:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = response;
```

Of course you now need to define a div in the page:

```
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```